# Visual Studio Shows errors until I open the *.aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, error-list

The Visual Studio Error List shows like 50 errors about controls and variables not existing.  I double click an error, it takes me to it, and after about 1 second they all go away!

There aren't any real errors, as my site compiles without errors or even warnings.

I know I've seen this before, but I forget how to fix it.  Anyone know why this is happening?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Examples? What error message? What did the code look like? Did you have the page open in the designer?

Comment: Just standard code... nothing fancy?  I'll try and get a sample of the one page it happened to.

Comment: Yup, happens all the time. It also seems to go away by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it often too on web sites.  I always have chalked it up to the compiler needing to "catch up" although I'm sure there is a more sophisticated answer to why that happens.  It's annoying.

Comment: I think it's not so much the compiler "catching up" as it is the compiler simply not having referential options at all. They don't have .proj files at all. Unless a class file happens to be open, Visual Studio doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before but I'm not sure what the actual cause is. I've seen it most using a website ASP.NET project rather than a web application ASP.NET project, but I don't know for certain that that's the cause.

That said, in my opinion you should use a web application style project *anyway* as it will pre-compile the most important portions of your application before deployment.